# Ajax get method one of the data is null how to handle

Tags: ajax, laravel

How do I approach this in Ajax

I have column name **level_id** and it accept null value

How do I set condition if level_id is `null` then display a text like **no level available** ?

**Here is my ajax get request**

```
////----- Open the modal to UPDATE a stream -----////
jQuery('body').on('click', '.open-modal', function () {
    var stream_id = $(this).val();
    $.get('streams/' + stream_id + '/edit', function (data) {
        jQuery('#stream_id').val(data.id);
        jQuery('#stream_name').val(data.name);
        jQuery('#stream_code').val(data.code);
        jQuery('#stream_level_name').val(data.level.name);
        jQuery('#btn-save').val("update");
        jQuery('#streamEditorModal').modal('show');
    })
});
```

**here is my laravel controller**

```
public function edit($uuid)
{
    $stream = Stream::with('level')->findOrFail($uuid);
    return response()->json($stream);
}
```

**This the console error.**

```
streams:435 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Object.success (streams:435)
    at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in this case ternary if

```
jQuery('#stream_name').val(data.name ? data.name : '-');
```

If name equally to null you change value to dash

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`fail`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) callback handler to handle error responses

```
$.getJSON('streams/' + stream_id + '/edit', function(data) {
    jQuery('#stream_id').val(data.id);
    jQuery('#stream_name').val(data.name);
    jQuery('#stream_code').val(data.code);
    jQuery('#stream_level_name').val(data.level.name);
    jQuery('#btn-save').val("update");
    jQuery('#streamEditorModal').modal('show');
}).fail(function () {
    // handle the error
});
```

and return the response appropriately

```
public function edit($uuid)
{
    return Stream::has('level')->with('level')->findOrFail($uuid);
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null